# Add events to cloned component

Tags: reactjs, events, clone

I'm using the following method to clone a component and modify its props.

```
    const clone = React.cloneElement(<BallComponent>, {
        key: new Date().getTime()
    });
```

How can I add a click event to this cloned component and call a function within its class when clicked?
I have tried the following with no luck:

```
    const clone = React.cloneElement(<BallComponent>, {
        key: new Date().getTime()}
        onClick: alert('test');
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're closing the props object curly brace before. Also, pass onClick a function rather than calling alert there which will execute right when the component mounts.

```
const clone = React.cloneElement(<BallComponent>, {
    key: new Date().getTime()
    onClick: () => { alert('test') }
});
```

This is a minimal example for the usage of `React.cloneElement`.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Demo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p onClick={this.props.click}>This is Demo. Click me.</p>;
  }
}

function App() {
  const clone = React.cloneElement(<Demo />, {
    click: () => {
      alert("You clicked Demo :)");
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {clone}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Below code snippet and it will work.

```
var Clone = React.cloneElement(<BallComponent/>, {
      key: new Date().getTime(),
      onClick: () => { alert('test') }
    });
```

> P.S.-Make sure BallComponent have onClick unless alert will not fire.

Answer (score 0):

In that example, you are executing `alert('test')` and assigning its return value to `onChange`, in this case `undefined`.

What you need is passing a function:

```
 const clone = React.cloneElement(<BallComponent>, {
        key: new Date().getTime()}
        onClick: () => { alert('test') };
    });
```